angular signal not updating afterNextRender()
Using angular SSR howcome, I have to manually trigger a change detection if I use afterNextRender. 
This is after all an angular API.
Does anyone have a solution for this?
    afterNextRender(() => {      
       this.someAPI.then((items) => {
         this.items.set(items); // <-- set signal
         this.ref.detectChanges(); // <--- trigger change detection
       });
       
    });

I do not want the API call to be made on the server side, that's why I use afterNextRender

something else that will update the signal is running the effect(() => console.log(this.items()))

Might be a bug. Signal should notify all "listeners" about its change. Given afterNextRender is in developer preview I would report it as a bug.

This is a zone issue.

afterNextRender/afterRender callbacks run outside the angular zone.
In v17, if you want to a signal update to trigger CD, you need to do it in the angular zone.
afterNextRender(() => {    
 this.someAPI.then((items) => {
   ngZone.run(() => {
     this.items.set(items); // <-- set signal
   });
  });
})

Note: In v18 Signals updates will trigger CD even when run outside the Angular zone

I was afraid of this boilerplate, I guess I hv no choice, ty

@fredtma v18 will probably improve that :)

@MatthieuRiegler so it is a bug?

This is a "feature", also note that v18 will improve over this. Signals will trigger CD even when outside the Angular zone.
